# Implementing single responsibility principle on a class that implements an interface with two responsibilities

Tags: java, oop, interface, rmi

I have an interface that I don't necessarily want to change without good reason as my client side program relies on it:

```
public interface RMIChatServer extends Remote {
public void connect(RMIChatClient theClient) throws RemoteException;
public void sendMessageToServer(String theMessage) throws RemoteException;
}
```

And I have a class RMIChatServerImpl that implements this functionality. I want to move the responsibility of sending the messages to another class, keeping to the principle of single responsibility.

Answer (score 4):

Implement the two methods in separate classes and then have your implementation of RMIChatServer delegate the calls to instances of the separate classes.

i.e.

```
class Connector {
      public void connect(RMIChatClient theClient) throws RemoteException {
      }
}

class Sender {
      public void sendMessageToServer(String theMessage) throws RemoteException {
      }
}

class ChatSender implements RMIChatServer {
     Connector connector = new Connector();
     Sender sender = new Sender();

     public void connect(RMIChatClient theClient) throws RemoteException {
         return connector.connect(theClient);
     }

     public void sendMessageToServer(String theMessage) throws RemoteException {
         return sender.sendMessageToServer(theMessage);
     }
}
```

I think you might be trying to push the single responsibility principle too far in this particular case though. Connecting to the server is a necessary prerequisite for sending a message to it so there is a valid argument to be made that it can be considered part of the same responsibility of communicating with the server rather than a separate responsibility.

Answer (score 0):

I'll give you a good reason to change the remote interface. Assuming that it should not be possible to send a message until you've connected, the connect() method should return another remote interface that contains the sendMessageToServer() method. The object that implements the send method shouldn't be in the Registry, it should only be accessible via the connect() method. That gives you a quasi-syntactic way of expressing the connect constraint. Then you can have your two implementation classes, separate the responsibilities, and improve the security of your system.